# Show location with Google search result

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-maps

I want to show the map for my business on the right side in search results, or at least show the pinpoint location sign with the address at the bottom of the result. I'm interested in the second link appearing for "Cursuri Autorizate" in the screenshot below:

[image: Google Location Snippet]

I have already created a Google+ business page for the business but it doesn't appear as I would want.

Comment: You can add the link to your Google+ page here as a comment, or inline in the question now.

Comment: This is the link to the google my business page.    https://plus.google.com/115505742652916495100/about

Comment: And this is the link to the profile the person has created not being aware that she creates a personal profile.  https://plus.google.com/114572837498930315269

Answer (score 2):

There are two main actions you can take to prompt this.

### Google My Business

Update your business details on [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/) so that you have a valid local listing to appear on the right side of search results, as well as in Google Maps.

> If you previously used Google Places for Business or Google+ Pages Dashboard to manage your business information, your account has been automatically upgraded to Google My Business. Google My Business makes it easier than ever to update business information across Google Search, Maps and Google+.

This will tie in with a Google+ page for your business, though the company address, logo, URL, & contact details are the important bits.

### LocalBusiness microdata

Implement [LocalBusiness Schema](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) into your website. Tagging the details on your website will corroborate what you have set with Google My Business and indicate to Google what to show as a rich snippet with your search results.